# node.js issue with brcypt on version 12.14.0

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt, nvm

I am getting bcrypt compatibility errors when installing/using node.js 12.14.0 (why 12.14.0.....that is the highest version currently supported by AWS).

here are the error messages, any idea how to resolve this issue.

Here is the complete setup scenario

1. working on ubuntu 18.*
2. removed all versions of node except for 12.14.0 using nvm
3. reinstalled all the packages using **sudo npm install**
4. ran the app, and, here are the errors

*node blah-blh.js*

Error: The module '/home/XXXXX/Desktop/app-current/ZZZZ-express/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).

After this I tried rebuilding using **npm rebuild**, still the same issue after rebuild finished

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands in your command line and it should work again.

1. `rm -rf node_modules`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source`

If the package name is not `bcrypt` you can change that part to be the name of the package you wish to rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for your input, unfortunately it did not work. Still getting the same errors. Also, tried to install latest version of bcrypt (3.0.7), and, still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

it does not work. l tried various solutions. seems binary are not available yet.

Answer (score 0):

replaced bcrypt with bcryptjs, it is written in javascript and does not need a compile/build and is a drop-in replacement for bcrypt.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem on windows by installing

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

On Linux I believe you can use node-gyp: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

Comment: I am using linux, node-gyp did not fix the problem, I think you maybe running older version of node, problem shows up only for more recent versions of node

Comment: What distribution are you using? If Ubuntu or its derivatives: have tried running `sudo apt-get install -y build-essential python` ? Installing node-gyp alone is not enough as it needs python to properly build bcrypt.